# How to create elements of form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, createelement, jquery-attributes

My code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                  </script>
    <script>
    function afterText() {
        var txt3 = document.createElement("b");   
        txt3.innerHTML = $("<input/>", {
        type: 'text',
        id: 'vname',
        name: 'name',
        placeholder: 'Your Name'
     });
     $("img").after(txt3);      
    }
    </script>
     </head>
  <body>
    <img src="/images/home.gif" alt="home" width="100" height="140">
    <button onclick="afterText()">click</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The output I got is [object Object]. But how can I add the input field(Append should not be used).

Comment: Why should append not be used?

Comment: Jquery did not reinvent the wheel new. As a matter of fact, Jquery summerised plain javascript methods into one call. So the method append() will be ever used :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to mix jQuery and pure JavaScript approaches for DOM manipulation.

Just use the following:

```
 $('<div>' +
     '<input type="text" id="vname" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">' +
   '</div>').insertAfter('img');
```

Or if you need it more advanced:

```
 $('<div>').append($('<input>', {
    type: 'text',
    id: 'vname',
    name: 'name',
    placeholder: 'Your Name'
 })).insertAfter('img');
```

Comment: Your answer is working. Thankyou!! How to show in popup instead of showing after image?